# SQLServer 2008 BIDS On Windows 7 - 64bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to install Sql Server 2008 Business Intelligence Development Suite on VS2008 in a Windows 7 (64bit) machine.

The installer is aborting with an unspecified error for which I have not been able to find any error anywhere.

Has anyone had the same problem with BIDS?

Thanks,

Eduardo Quiros-Campos

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the install to work by installing SQL Server 2008 SP1 then attempting the BIDS install again.  I believe you will need to apply SP1 again after installing the additional components, but this workaround got me the BI projects in VS2008.

Hope that helps